# Pandas - How do you iterate over cols and move them into a new position whilst matching them to rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset similar to the one below:

| tag1 | Desc | 07/07/23 | 14/07/23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TVG | text1 | 153 | 35 |
| UGY | text2 | 5 | 88 |
| EXT | text3 | 46 | 46 |

My aim is to have the end result be:

| tag1 | Desc | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TVG | text1 | 153 | 07/07/23 |
| TVG | text1 | 35 | 14/07/23 |
| UGY | text2 | 5 | 07/07/23 |
| UGY | text2 | 88 | 14/07/23 |
| EXT | text3 | 46 | 07/07/23 |
| EXT | text3 | 46 | 14/07/23 |

I having a hard time accurately describing what I want to do verbally, but effectively I want to tie the date values and their values to the rows based on the tag and the description. I will add more detail and clarity as I am able, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df.melt(['tag1','Desc'])`?

Comment: do you want 'iterate'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.melt()`:

```py
df.melt(["tag1", "Desc"], var_name="Date", value_name="Value")
```

This outputs:

```py
   tag1    Desc      Date Value
0  TVG   text1   07/07/23  153
1  UGY   text2   07/07/23    5
2  EXT   text3   07/07/23   46
3  TVG   text1   14/07/23   35
4  UGY   text2   14/07/23   88
5  EXT   text3   14/07/23   46
```

Comment: This was exactly it thank you; I'd never really understood what melt() did, guess I need to go back and read up on it.